# Notepad++ Template Collapse Issue

Tags: javascript, html, notepad++, jquery-templates, knockout.js

I have been working with Notepad++ for web development for a few months now.  As I continue to work with it, I am more and more pleased with its setup.  One thing really bothers me, though.  When working with a JQuery template, not all of the contents of the script are recognized.  The program will highlight and collapse only up until the first closing tag contained within the script tag.

For example:

```
<script id="itemTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li class="row">
        <div class="rowTextContainer">
            <div class="rowTitle">${title}</div>
            <div class="rowSubTitle">${subTitle}</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</script>
```

The above code would collapse down to:

```
<script id="itemTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div class="rowSubTitle">${subTitle}</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</script>
```

Which is certainly not correct.  Is there a fix or at least a workaround for this issue?  I've just updated to version 5.9 and this is still a problem for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three options (increasing level of difficulty):

One is to use `Language -> XML`. The side effect is that the color scheme changes (but that can be fixed with settings).

Second, create your own [user defined language](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/25/creating-a-user-defined-language-in-notepad.aspx). 
I created one but for some reason, syntax highlighting is not working: http://pastebin.com/BxRvbbQV

Build your own [lexer](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/languages/external-lexers)

Comment: Actually, I'm just giving this to you now.  You introduced me to a feature I completely overlooked.

Comment: Glad to be of help! Which one did you overlook? On a side note, I would suggest moving the template to a script file. You will benefit by browser caching. So I guess this is an acceptable answer? :)

Comment: You bet it's acceptable!  I realized I forgot to click the "accept" button about 30 seconds before you posted this, haha.  I completely overlooked creating a lexer.  Also, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Notepad++ is expecting the lines between the 2 script tags to be Javascript, not html. I've actually never seen type="text/html" in a script before. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm actually using Knockout.js in the page I pulled this example from, so I might have a slightly different setup.  It seems to work fine programming-wise.  This highlighting/collapsing problem happens no matter what I have as the type, though.

Comment: Notepadd++ assumes there will be Javascript between <script> tags. If you look closely, it's trying to format the html code as Javascript. This is why it's having trouble collapsing. I don't think there's anything you can do.

Comment: That's pretty much the answer I was expecting. Maybe there is someone with a workaround somewhere on here, still. Thanks for your help, Josh.

Comment: Yeah, its because of HTML inside `script` tags. Tried a few tricks like wrapping inside CDATA but didn't work.